# Store checkbox value in the database whether is checked or not in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, checkbox

I'm really confused and I don't know why I've forgotten the way of doing this.

I want to store a checkbox value in the database when it's checked and unchecked. For example, store 0 when it's unchecked and 1 when it's checked.

This a piece of my code:

```
$course_Notifier = array('name' => 'course_Notifier', 'value' => set_checkbox(course_Notifier, 1); 

echo form_checkbox($course_Notifier);
```

I know that it's really easy, But I completely have forgotten the way of doing it.

Comment: Typically, a 'hidden' value is used. The form parser always takes the 'last' value associated with a given variable, so as long as the hidden value appears before the checked value, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that would help. Try this out

```
$course_Notifier = array('name' => 'course_Notifier', 'value' => set_checkbox(course_Notifier, 1); 

echo form_hidden('course_Notifier', 0);
echo form_checkbox($course_Notifier);
```